# R BH package not showing "asio" directory

Tags: r, boost, boost-asio, rcpp

After installing BH package, including following in .cpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
#include <boost/asio/ip/address_v4.hpp>
```

sourcing the cpp file with `sourceCpp(".cpp file")` is giving :

> fatal error: boost/asio/ip/address_v4.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

In BH/boost directory there is no asio directory.

Comment: I've got a cpl packages that require ASIO. Good luck getting it to work on Windows, but it *is* quite doable on Linux & OS X. Check out the `iptools` package on CRAN. Since my stuff also works with IP addresses it shld be a a good comparison for you.

Answer (score 3):

We never said Boost Asio was part of BH.  Quoting from [the DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/bh/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L8-15) with my highlighting in italics below:

> **Description:** Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source
>   libraries.  *A large part of Boost is provided as C++ template code
>   which is resolved entirely at compile-time without linking.*  This
>   package aims to provide the most useful subset of Boost libraries 
>   for template use among CRAN package. By placing these libraries in
>   this package, we offer a more efficient distribution system for CRAN
>   as replication of this code in the sources of other packages is
>   avoided.

Asio, thread, ... and a few others require linking and can never be part of BH.